# What can PostgreSQL do that MySQL cannot in regard to the NoSQL features?

Tags: mysql, postgresql, nosql

I am trying to understand NoSQL and since PostgreSQL is both ACID compliant and implements NoSQL features, can you give examples of what PostGreSQL can do that MySQL cannot in regard to the NoSQL features that the former implements ?

Comment: NoSQL is not a thing it's an Un-thing.  what features are you interested in?

Answer (score 1):

Now that also mysql user Json datatype the main difference are related  to the

```
 use of array data type
```

and

```
 HStore datatype   (key value pair)
```

Answer (score 1):

PostgreSQL has `json`, `jsonb` and `hstore` (not sure if `array` makes sense in that context). Whereas MySQL, besides having `JSON` which is equivalent to pg's `jsonb` now also has a specific [document store](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/document-store.html) interface.

I'm not entirely sure of the benefits of `hstore` vs the alternatives. But with regards to `JSON` support, I would say things are pretty even (PostgreSQL might have a better indexing infrastructure as far as I'm aware). However, it's still SQL. On the other hand, if you are looking for something in the lines of a MongoDB-style CRUD API, MySQL has you covered.

Disclaimer: I work in the MySQL connectors team at Oracle.